# UIDatePicker won't scroll

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker in my project that will not scroll. The column scrolls down and bounces back - it also floats off to one side before floating back to the original value as if it were stuck.

I am using Xcode 7.2 with a deployment target of 8.0. I am using storyboard with auto layout - I also tried adding the datePicker programmatically to no avail. I ran another project on the simulator with a datePicker and it worked fine - I moved those files into my project and the datePicker stopped working. this is maddening and I hope someone has come across and solved this problem already - I couldn't find anything on SO or the WWW that solved the problem. Could it be a corrupt storyboard file or something?

Comment: I wound up solving this issue by adding the datePicker programmatically and then setting the date and minuteInterval separately from awakeFromNib.

Comment: I solved this issue by adding datePicker programmatically and setting the date & minuteInterval separately from awakeFromNib.
`- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    self.datePicker.backgroundColor = FlatWhiteDark;
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.datePicker];
}
- (void)configureDatePickerForTitle:(NSString *)title {
    self.datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
    self.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    self.datePicker.minuteInterval = 15;
    [self.datePicker setDatel:[NSDate date] animated:YES];
}`